# Barra de rolagem na horizontal não aparece ao usar datatable

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css3

Tenho uma tela onde os dados são mostrados na seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao acessar em telas menores (celulares,tablets), o datatable aparece cortado, entretanto não aparece a barra de rolagem horizontal, sendo assim o usuário não consegue ver a outra metade da tabela. O que poderia fazer?

**Obs:** Esse problema só surgiu depois que comecei a usar datatable, pois se eu usar uma tabela normal a rolagem aparece.

Comment: Já tentou? https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/

Comment: @DiegoFelipe sim, estou usando.

Answer (score 2):

Deve ter algum

```
 overflow: hidden;
```

no CSS do container pai do datatable ou até no body, por isso, em resolução menores, a tela diminui e o conteúdo some.
Só tira ele ou modificar para

```
 overflow: auto;
```

Que é resolvido :)

Comment: não tem, já verifiquei. Esse problema só surgiu depois que comecei a usar datatable, pois se eu usar uma tabela normal a rolagem aparece.

Comment: O datatable utilixa/adiciona algum CSS dele mesmo? Pode ta lá o problema.

Comment: @jonnierhenrique mesmo colocando: .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody {
  *margin-top: -1px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody th > div.dataTables_sizing,
.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_scroll div.dataTables_scrollBody td > div.dataTables_sizing {
  height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

não adiantou

Answer (score 2):

Para telas menores eu costumo usar uma div com a classe Table-responsive englobando a tabela. Espero que tenha ajudado.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português Daniel. Isto parece ser mais um comentário que uma resposta. Seria interessante adicionar mais informações e até mesmo um exemplo para que seja uma resposta mais completa e válida.

Comment: pode especificar mais @DanielNicodemos?

Comment: Agradecemos você querer ajudar! No entanto você usou o campo de resposta para fazer um comentário. O campo de resposta deverá apenas ser utilizado para postar uma solução ao problema que a pergunta coloca.
Você poderá postar comentários quando tiver [mais pontos de reputação.](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: @Bia, modifiquei a resposta acima colocando um exemplo sobre a classe na div :)